# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module in Intellij while running Kafka App?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I've been working on an application that collects the live streaming bitcoin transaction data online using Websocket API and analyses it on the go. I created the Kafka producer to collect data from a specific topic. I'm using Intellij, Scala, and Kafka to develop the application.

For I'm working on the Kafka producer part.

My code file structure is src/scala/main/coinyser.

This is the first file(src/scala/main/coinyser/StreamingProducer.scala):

```
package coinyser

import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.TimeZone

import cats.effect.IO
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.pusher.client.Client
import com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging

object StreamingProducer extends StrictLogging {

  def subscribe(pusher: Client)(onTradeReceived: String => Unit): IO[Unit] = {
    for {
      _ <- IO(pusher.connect())
      channel <- IO(pusher.subscribe("live_trades"))

      _ <- IO(channel.bind("trade", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        override def onEvent(channel: String, event: String, data:
        String): Unit = {
          logger.info(s"Received event: $event with data: $data")
          onTradeReceived(data)
        }
      }))
    } yield ()
  }

  val mapper: ObjectMapper = {
//    println("I'm running!")
//    val m = new ObjectMapper()
    val m = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    m.setDateFormat(sdf)
  }

  def deserializeWebsocketTransaction(s: String): WebsocketTransaction = {
    mapper.readValue(s, classOf[WebsocketTransaction])
  }

  def convertWsTransaction(wsTx: WebsocketTransaction): Transaction =
    Transaction(
      timestamp = new Timestamp(wsTx.timestamp.toLong * 1000), tid =
        wsTx.id, price = wsTx.price, sell = wsTx.`type` == 1, amount =
        wsTx.amount)

  def serializeTransaction(tx: Transaction): String =
    mapper.writeValueAsString(tx)
}
```

This is second file(src/main/scala/coinyser/StreamingProducerApp.scala):

```
package coinyser

import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import com.pusher.client.Pusher
import StreamingProducer._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object StreamingProducerApp extends IOApp {
  val topic = "transactions"

  val pusher = new Pusher("de504dc5763aeef9ff52")

  val props = Map(
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
    "key.serializer" ->
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer",
    "value.serializer" ->
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer[Int, String](props)

    subscribe(pusher) { wsTx =>
      val tx = convertWsTransaction(deserializeWebsocketTransaction(wsTx))
      val jsonTx = serializeTransaction(tx)
      kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, tx.tid, jsonTx))
    }.flatMap(_ => IO.never)
  }
}
```

When I try to run my StreamingProducerApp.scala to stream the live data I get this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module
    at coinyser.StreamingProducerApp$.run(StreamingProducerApp.scala:24)
    at cats.effect.IOApp$$anonfun$main$2.apply(IOApp.scala:68)
    at cats.effect.IOApp$$anonfun$main$2.apply(IOApp.scala:68)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOAppPlatform$$anonfun$mainFiber$2.apply(IOAppPlatform.scala:43)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOAppPlatform$$anonfun$mainFiber$2.apply(IOAppPlatform.scala:42)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.liftedTree3$1(IORunLoop.scala:217)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.step(IORunLoop.scala:217)
    at cats.effect.IO.unsafeRunTimed(IO.scala:317)
    at cats.effect.IO.unsafeRunSync(IO.scala:251)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOAppPlatform$.main(IOAppPlatform.scala:28)
    at cats.effect.IOApp$class.main(IOApp.scala:68)
    at coinyser.StreamingProducerApp$.main(StreamingProducerApp.scala:9)
    at coinyser.StreamingProducerApp.main(StreamingProducerApp.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 13 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

build.sbt file:

```
name := "bitcoin-analyser"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
val sparkVersion = "2.3.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % "test",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.0.0-RC2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "com.pusher" % "pusher-java-client" % "1.8.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "1.1.1")

scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"

// Avoids SI-3623
target := file("/tmp/sbt/bitcoin-analyser")

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
test in assembly := {}

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

mainClass in assembly := Some("coinyser.BatchProducerAppSpark")
```

Can anyone help me out why this error is occurring and tell me solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added ObjectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) method to my code and it worked.

```
package coinyser

import java.net.URI
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.TimeZone

import cats.effect.IO
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.pusher.client.Client
import com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SaveMode}

object StreamingProducer extends StrictLogging {

  def subscribe(pusher: Client)(onTradeReceived: String => Unit): IO[Unit] =
    for {
      _ <- IO(pusher.connect())
      channel <- IO(pusher.subscribe("live_trades"))

      _ <- IO(channel.bind("trade", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        override def onEvent(channel: String, event: String, data: String): Unit = {
          logger.info(s"Received event: $event with data: $data")
          onTradeReceived(data)
        }
      }))
    } yield ()


  val mapper: ObjectMapper = {
    val m = new ObjectMapper()
    m.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    // Very important: the storage must be in UTC
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    m.setDateFormat(sdf)

    // Added disable method to ObjectMapper to get rid of compile time warning
    m.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
  }

  def deserializeWebsocketTransaction(s: String): WebsocketTransaction =
    mapper.readValue(s, classOf[WebsocketTransaction])

  def convertWsTransaction(wsTx: WebsocketTransaction): Transaction =
    Transaction(
      timestamp = new Timestamp(wsTx.timestamp.toLong * 1000), tid = wsTx.id,
      price = wsTx.price, sell = wsTx.`type` == 1, amount = wsTx.amount)

  def serializeTransaction(tx: Transaction): String =
    mapper.writeValueAsString(tx)

  def unsafeSave(transactions: Dataset[Transaction], path: URI): Unit =
    transactions
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .partitionBy("date")
      .parquet(path.toString)

  def save(transactions: Dataset[Transaction], path: URI): IO[Unit] =
    IO(unsafeSave(transactions, path))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`spark-sql-kafka-0-10` already includes `kafka-clients`, which in turn each import Jackson , and declaring a different version for them will have classpath exceptions like this

Although, it's not clear why you even need Spark or Hadoop since you're just using plain Kafka Producer API and never initializing a Spark object

Comment: Thanks this worked. I'm using Spark streaming to subscribe to the Kafka topic and analyze the data.

Comment: Why not use regular consumer or kafka streams? Or at least separate out the consumer code as a separate jar / application

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the issue in my local and it seems like there is a conflict the jackson imports in the StreamingProducer class. Could you please try the below imports and let me know how it goes? Just replace lines 8 & 9

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
```

Comment: I changed lines 8 & 9 with 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

But it is showing the same error again.

Comment: @RajaShekar I am assuming WebSocket transaction is your model ?

Comment: Yes it is WebSocket transaction.

Comment: @RajaShekar I used the above imports & changed the scala vesion to `2.12.8` & sparkVersion to `2.4.4` and it worked like a charm. Give it a try once and let me know how it ends up. Thanks !

Comment: Still getting the same error. In my built.properties the sbt.version is set to 1.2.7. Do I need to make any changes to it?